# Plot Seismic Volume walls in Petrel 3D window using ocean

Tags: c#, ocean, petrel

Can I programmatically plot a 3D seismic data volume render in 3D window through ocean?

I can plot a random inline/xline with Window3d.showobject(seismic_cube) but i want to see the volume render directly without going into the setting tab.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to display seismic data in volume render format using Ocean.